# Swift Add UIView with subviews to titleView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview, titleview

I'd like to customize my navigation bar and insert a UIView with two subviews into the title view of the navigation bar.
Unfortunately the subviews aren't displayed.
Do you have any idea why?

```
    let titleContainer = UIView()
    titleContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)

    let searchIcon = UIButton()
    searchIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "search_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    searchIcon.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 28) / 2, width: 28, height: 28)
    titleContainer.addSubview(searchIcon)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 28, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-28, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:255, green:255, blue:255, alpha:1.0)
    titleContainer.addSubview(self.titleLabel)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleContainer
```

problem and expected solution:

[image]

Comment: Your  all the frames are  UIScreeen Main screen that  big .  as you are using `UIScreen.main.bounds` provide valid frames then it should display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use `height` of all the element as `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height`? Please try the below code.

P.S. I have changed the color of `searchIcon` as i didn't have the image and changed the color of text of label and added some text so that it is visible.

```
    let titleContainer = UIView()
    titleContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 45)

    let searchIcon = UIButton()
    //searchIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "search_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    searchIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    searchIcon.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: 28, height: 28)
    titleContainer.addSubview(searchIcon)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 28, y: 8, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-28, height: 30)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue//(red:255, green:255, blue:255, alpha:1.0)
    titleContainer.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.text = "Sample Text"

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleContainer
```

Here is the screenshot of the above code:

[image]

Please change the x,y accordingly as per your requirement.

Comment: you opened my eyes again :D the problem was the screen height, thanks so much

Comment: Happy that it helped... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making your `let bar = UINavigationBar()` programmatically and then add it with: `self.view.addSubview(bar)`?

So you can push all the "UIBarItems" you want..?

Comment: I also have it in my storyboard, that's why I haven't programmed the Navbar. The thing is, if I add the titleLabel or searchIcon by itself it is displayed. But if I add the container with the subviews nothing shows up.